# MySQL table partitioning on date

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have  a table (innodb) that will have billions of records eventually. Every 2nd week I expect ~ 500K records to get dropped into the table. I would want to partition this table based on the date on which the data is imported - luckily this is a field in the table that is of the format yyyy-mm-dd - Is it possible to partition it based on this date column ? I tried looking at the 18th chapter of mysql docs but couldn't figure out if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot partition on a date column directly, but you can partition on `TO_DAYS(thedatecolumn)`. There's some examples [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_5.1_partitioning_with_dates.html)